# Run a script with web server and maintain data to be used later

Tags: python, web-applications, process, subprocess

Note: I want to implement this without using any framework.

I have to create an web application using python. The application should maintain a running average of the CPU usage for each process over the past 60 seconds. It should should act as a web server and when it gets a request, it should return the current average for each process. Following are the scripts I've written. **record_usage.py** is a script which I want to run as soon as the **server.py** is run. So that it runs and maintain the cpu usage data, which I intend to read whenever I get an XHR request and send it back to the client.

So, my problem is how do I invoke this requirement? I tried running **record_usage.py** using **subprocess.POPEN** after starting the server. **record_usage.py** starts running in background as well. But when I try accessing the data created by it, the class object I create is not the one it uses but a new one. How to complete this link?

Kindly ask things that I could not make clear.

**Latest changes in server.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    RU_OBJ = RU(settings.SAMPLING_FREQ, settings.AVG_INTERVAL)
    RU_LOCK = RLock()
    # Record CPU usage in a thread.
    ru_thread = Thread(target=RU_OBJ.record, args=(RU_LOCK,))
    ru_thread.daemon = True
    ru_thread.start()

    # Run server.
    run()
```

**Latest change in record_usage.py**

```
def record(self, lock):
    while True:
        with lock:
            self.add_processes()
        time.sleep(self.sampling_freq)
```

Is this a proper way of applying locks? A similar lock is being applied when am reading the processes information. Would it work?

Added the functions:

```
def add_processes(self,):
    for _process in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            new_proc = _process.as_dict(attrs=['cpu_times', 'name', 'pid',
                                               'status'])
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            continue
        pid, (user, _sys) = new_proc['pid'], new_proc.pop('cpu_times')
        # Get or create details object for the process.
        existing = self.processes.setdefault(pid, new_proc)
        # Get or create queue object for the CPU times of the process.
        queue_dict = self.process_queue.setdefault(pid, dict())
        # User CPU time.
        user_q = queue_dict.setdefault('user_q', PekableQueue(self.avg_interval))
        user_q.enqueue(user)
        user_avg = get_avg(user_q)
        # System CPU time.
        sys_q = queue_dict.setdefault('sys_q', PekableQueue(self.avg_interval))
        sys_q.enqueue(_sys)
        sys_avg = get_avg(sys_q)
        # Update the details object for the process.
        existing.update(user_avg=user_avg, sys_avg=sys_avg, **new_proc)

def get_curr_processes(self):
    return [self.processes[pid] for pid in psutil.get_pid_list()
            if pid in self.processes]
```

Comment: It is not clear what *"this requirement"* refers to. The simplest solution is to collect the statistics in a different thread instead of  different process

Comment: @JFSebastian this requirement is communicating the statistics to the server. Could you please use a small example to do this using thread?

Comment: why do you think you need a lock here?

Comment: because the dictionary might be modified while it is being read. so there might be an inconsistency in data for diff processes with respect to the time which they are produced. am i wrong thinking this?

Comment: what dictionary? The less code the lock protects, the better (use it near your dictionary, don't wrap the whole method). Lock is useless unless  it is used in at least two threads. You don't need `RLock` unless you need to acquire it recursively

Comment: so my requirement doesn't need lock here?

Comment: what is "my requirement"?

Comment: Thread implementation of backend to cater statistics and render them on UI, both at an interval of 1 sec.

Comment: it is not specific enough to judge. Do you access the same dictionary from several threads?

Comment: Not several threads. I update it in the thread i am creating and read it from the server get method in the script i'm invoking thread from.

Comment: two threads (the main thread with the server and the background thread with `record_usage`) means *"several"* for the purpose of using locks. show *two* lines where you read or change values in the dictionary

Comment: Added the functions. get_curr_process I read, add_process I update. Once at the beginning to add new ones. then at the end to update new or the existing ones.

Comment: you call `add_processes` method in the "record_usage" thread and "get_curr_processes" method in the server thread on *the same* `RecordUsage` object. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. I do the same. Sat on system after long time. This text is to complete 15 chars of the comment B-)

Comment: Thanks for your patience and guidelines. I have implemented it [Here](https://github.com/trash-anshu/CPU_USAGE/tree/master/cpu_usage)

Comment: Now the big task done, I want to write test cases for the application I have written. I have gone through the unittest library's doc and have understood the theory written there. Now, in order to write test cases for [this script](https://github.com/trash-anshu/CPU_USAGE/blob/master/cpu_usage/app/server.py) for example, which functions and methods do I have to write tests for? Will I have to run a temp server to do it? How to move ahead with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To collect statistics in another thread:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from threading import Thread, Lock
    import record_usage

    lock = Lock()
    t = Thread(target=record_usage.record, args=[lock])
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    run(lock)
```

If you change some shared data in one thread and read it in another then you could protect the places where you access/change the value with a lock:

```
#...
with self.lock:
    existing = self.processes.setdefault(pid, new_proc)
#...
with self.lock:
    existing.update(user_avg=user_avg, sys_avg=sys_avg, **new_proc)
#...

def get_curr_processes(self):
    with self.lock:
        return [self.processes[pid] for pid in psutil.get_pid_list()
                if pid in self.processes]
```

It is essential that `self.lock` is the same object in all threads. If `self.processes` is a `dict` then you don't need to use a lock in CPython. The methods are implemented in C and the interpreter doesn't release GIL (global lock) while calling them i.e., only one thread at a time accesses the `dict`.

Comment: @jfsebastian I have done some edit in the problem statement at the end. This is related to applying locks on the thread. Is it a proper way? I don't see any exception. But how do I know if the lock is working?

Comment: is same applicable for lists as well?